# Installing Ubuntu on MacBook Pro VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, macbook-pro

I try to install Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro using VirtualBox. However, there seems to be no guide on how to do this-—most are about installing on Windows PC using VirtualBox.

Would someone help direct me on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Virtual Box up and running ? If yes, you can follow a Windows guide for the installation since the procedure would be the same. Or are you stuck at a specific step ?

Answer (score 3):

The procedure is pretty much identical to windows computers. You get the ISO for [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and configure a new VM through the [Virtualbox GUI](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) how you like it. After configuration is complete, double click the VM to open, and choose your ISO file. Then, wait for it to boot up. After that, go through normal installation. When it asks you to restart, restart. When it asks you to remove install media and press enter, press enter. VirtualBox will automatically remove the install media for you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm running 20.04 in VirtualBox 6.1.10 on MacOS 10.15.  Per other answers follow the wizard and it all just works.

1. download from https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
2. follow wizard on MacOS to setup
3. alternatively example doing from command line using python as controller. This is pretty much host OS independent - just way paths are built would not work in PowerShell.  The default preseed config files on MacOS hence use of custom files with patching

```
def vbinstall(alog, config, buildkey):
    name = buildkey
    home = Path.home()
    download = f"{Path.cwd()}/downloads/{config['ubuntu'][buildkey]['dl'].split('/')[-1]}"
    vb = hm.vbhost(host=config["virtualbox"])
    cfg = f"{Path.cwd()}/bin/UnattendedTemplates/ubuntu_preseed.cfg"
    exit, out = vb.cmd("VBoxManage list vms")
    # alog.info(f"shared folder {config['sharedstorage']} -exists ")
    alog.info(f"shared folder [{config['sharedstorage']}] exists [{Path(config['sharedstorage']).is_dir()}]")
    for l in out:
        vms = l.split()[0].strip("\"")
        if vms == name:
            alog.info(f"Server exists {vms}.  Skipping setup....")
            return
    aux = f"{Path.cwd()}/bin/UnattendedTemplates/aux-{buildkey}"
    alog.info(f"aux {aux}")
    exit, out = vb.cmd(f"rm -rf {aux}")
    exit, out = vb.cmd(f"mkdir {aux}")
    with open(f"{Path.cwd()}/bin/UnattendedTemplates/autoinstall.yaml") as f: aconfig=yaml.safe_load(f)
    # aconfig["autoinstall"]["hostname"] = buildkey
    aconfig["autoinstall"]["identity"]["hostname"] = buildkey
    aconfig["autoinstall"]["identity"]["username"] = config['mcs']['user']
    aconfig["autoinstall"]["identity"]["password"] = config['mcs']['encrypted']
    # substitute @@user@@ in late commands
    aconfig["autoinstall"]["late-commands"] = \
        [re.sub("\@\@user\@\@", config['mcs']['user'], l) for l in aconfig["autoinstall"]["late-commands"]]
    with open(f"{aux}/autoinstall.yaml", "w") as f:
        f.write("#cloud-config\n")
        yaml.dump(aconfig, f)
    with open(f"{aux}/user-data", "w") as f:
        f.write("#cloud-config\n")
        yaml.dump(aconfig, f)
    exit, out = vb.cmd(f"touch {aux}/meta-data")

    # want to keep UUID of VM constant for remoteit and plex - if defined use it
    uuid = f'--uuid {config["ubuntu"][name]["uuid"]}' if "uuid" in config["ubuntu"][name].keys() else ""
    # allow for VM specific location of sharedfolder
    sharedstorage = config["ubuntu"][name]["sharedstorage"] if "sharedstorage" in config["ubuntu"][name].keys() else \
                            config["sharedstorage"]
    alog.info(f"uuid: [{uuid}] storage: [{sharedstorage}]")

    # VBoxManage createvm --name {name} --ostype \"Ubuntu_64\" --register --basefolder {home}/\"VirtualBox VMs\"/
    vbi =    f'''
VBoxManage createvm --name {name} --ostype \"Ubuntu_64\" --register --basefolder {home}/\"VirtualBox VMs\"/ {uuid}
#Set memory and network
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --ioapic off
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --memory 1024 --vram 128
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --nic1 bridged
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --bridgeadapter1 'en0: en0'
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --graphicscontroller vmsvga
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --audio none
#Create Disk and connect Debian Iso
VBoxManage createhd --filename {home}/\"VirtualBox VMs\"/{name}_DISK.vdi --size 15000 --format VDI
VBoxManage createhd --filename {sharedstorage}/{buildkey}-plex.vhd --size 50000 --format VHD
VBoxManage storagectl {name} --name "SATA Controller" --add sata --controller IntelAhci
VBoxManage storageattach {name} --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium  {home}/\"VirtualBox VMs\"/{name}_DISK.vdi
VBoxManage storageattach {name} --storagectl "SATA Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type hdd --medium  {sharedstorage}/{buildkey}-plex.vhd

# shared storage
VBoxManage sharedfolder add {name} --name mcs --hostpath {sharedstorage} --automount
VBoxManage sharedfolder add {name} --name active --hostpath "{config['ubuntu'][name]['media']['active']}" --automount
VBoxManage sharedfolder add {name} --name archive --hostpath "{config['ubuntu'][name]['media']['archive']}" --automount

#Enable RDP
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --vrde on
VBoxManage modifyvm {name} --vrdemulticon on --vrdeport 10001

# install
VBoxManage unattended install {name} --user={config['mcs']['user']} --password={config['mcs']['pwd']} \
    --auxiliary-base-path {aux}/ \
    --install-additions --iso={download} --country=SG  --post-install-template={cfg} --script-template={cfg}
    '''
    exit, out = vb.cmd(vbi, assertfail=False)
    for l in out: alog.info(f"{l}")
    alog.info(f"finished {name} initial setup")
    isolinux(aux, buildkey, config, alog)
    preseed(aux, buildkey, config, alog)
    exit, out = vb.cmd(f"VBoxManage startvm {name} #--type headless", assertfail=False)
    alog.info(f"vm start [{exit}] {out}")
```